# NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.security.ProtectionDomain)

Tags: spring-boot, jaxb, java-17

I'm migrating java project from JDK8 to JDK17 and I'm stuck.
I tried a few fixes from google but it doesn't work.

```
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:573)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.<clinit>(Injector.java:197)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:81)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:179)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:285)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.<init>(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:92)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:128)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:181)
```

is thrown on line:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
```

I use:

- the latest version of spring boot
- java 17 amazon corretto

Comment: As the exception’s name suggest, the method `sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass` does not exist (anymore). The framework needs to be updated to a version not using this removed internal API but the official API which has been introduced in Java 9.

Comment: Can you share `mvn dependency:tree` of your project? Do you have `org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime` in your dependency tree and what's its version? Next question, how do you package and run your project?